# Fast double click on button vote results in scrolling up the page on Chrome for Android (responsive mode off)

Tags: bug, voting, responsive-design, android, mobile-chrome

Fast double click on button vote results in scrolling up the page on Chrome for Android (responsive mode off).

Demo: https://youtu.be/guiB_8-XLg8

Bug present when responsive mode is off. Absent when responsive mode on.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the scroll to top behavior on SO in mobile mode. It seems the bug is present in mobile mode on any site.

Comment: Keep in mind dark mode isn't even available for mobile mode so you were probably using the "full site" mode for SO.

Comment: @KodosJohnson thanks, yes, I use responsive mode on aka full site. Are you able to reproduce the bug on SO on Chrome on Android with responsive mode on and dark mode on? I can't.

Comment: nope, I can't reproduce in responsive mode with the dark theme OR light theme on **any** site. It only happens in mobile mode.

Comment: with that in mind, I think your title is wrong. The responsive mode is fine, it's the mobile mode that has the bug (as can be seen in your screen recording).

Comment: @KodosJohnson Thanks, you're correct, I didn't realize that [when switching to full site on mobile phone, the setting is lost when going to another Stack Exchange website](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349928/178179).